# Compare two data frames and conditionally extract the value of another column

Tags: r, finance

I have two tables, quotes and trades. I need to extract the BidPrice of the quote where the timestamp of the quote is less than the timestamp of the trade. How do I create a loop or function that will compare the first quote timestamp and then proceed to the need quote timestamp?

I've tried for loops, nested for loops, creating my own function but the result is either the first BidPrice of the data frame or condenses all the BidPrices into one vector.

```
for(i in 1:length(trades_reduced_f100[,3])){
  #outer loop is running. It is going up to 100
  for(j in 1:length(quotes_reduced_f100[,3])){
    while(quotes_reduced_f100$Timestamp[j] <= trades_reduced_f100$Timestamp){
      trades_reduced_f100$BidPrice[i] <- subset(quotes_reduced_f100)$BidPrice
      # print(trades_reduced_f100$BidPrice[i])
    break
    }

  }
}
```

I expect the output to be a different BidPrice as the loop runs through the quote timestamp, but the output is just the first BidPrice for all. That means that the loop is getting stuck at the first quote.

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve using two nested for loops as shown in the example.

Code:

```
for(i in 1:length(trades_full[,3])){
  for(j in 1:length(quotes[,3])){
    if(quotes$Timestamp[j] <= trades_full$Timestamp[i] & 
       quotes$Timestamp[j+1] > trades_full$Timestamp[i]){
         trades_full$BidPrice[i] <- quotes$BidPrice[j]
    break
  } 
 }
}
```

However, run over the large data set the processing speed is very slow. What are some alternate methods that perhaps won't take as much time/are more efficient?

Comment: Hello, could you provide a small reproducible example of your data. This would make it much easier to help solve you problem. using `dput()` on your data would do the trick, otherwise you would need to create some pseudo data that can be replicated if your data is private.

Comment: I think you're going to want to have some intermediate step there where you have some kind of `output[j]<-subset(quotes_reduced_f100)$BidPrice` rather than going straight to `trades_reduced_f100$BidPrice[i]`. The way it is now, for each `j`, you're just going to be replacing the same value, rather than adding something new.